# typo3 - building a simple functionality

Tags: typo3

I am building a fairly simple website based on typo3. I'm new to the CMS but I've read almost everything I could find about it - tutorials, wikis, documentation. I'm stuck with designing a functionality for the administrator to be able to create records with predefined attributes (category, date, info, image, ...) and those records to be listed in a table on the front end with a "View detailed" link on each row. Will I need to develop a complete extension for this? From where the administrator will enter these records? How can I iterate them on the front end?

I apologize in advance if my question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kickstarter](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kickstarter/current/) extension provides a full stop solution for your needs. There is a good set of, if slightly outdated, [screencasts](http://typo3.org/documentation/videos/wmv-format/#c2375) explaining how to use this extension to create your custom record types and associated front-end views.

Comment: Thank you. I am building my extension now with the kickstarter. I've managed to design my tables and relations, also I've set it so I can create records in Lists tab and insert the plugin in a page where the result will go. Everything seems to be OK, except that my plugin doesn't return anything to the page. It's not even executed. Have I missed something?

Comment: Well it's kind of hard to tell what might be wrong, based only on what you've written. Did you create a front-end plugin inside your extension? If you look at the generated source, there should be a you_extension/pi1 directory, containing a class.your_extension_pi1.php file. This should contain the code for front-end rendering. Try your debugging from there.

Comment: Yes, everything is set. I have the php file, there's a class with a main() method in it. I inserted the plugin in one of the pages but nothing returned from the plugin is shown on the page. I created a very simple plugin from the kickstarter. Could this be a cache problem or an option I missed to check in the kickstarter?

Comment: In that case, I'd say it must be a cache problem.